# jQuery ajax get intermittently fails

Tags: jquery, get

I have two different endpoints, same exact parameters.  One works perfectly every time.  The second fails everytime UNLESS a breakpoint is put on the ajax call and single stepped once.  Then and only then does it contact the second endpoint.  In the FF debugger it still is not calling the callback function as when it is on the server, the breakpoint is released and single step needs to be clicked again for the callback to be called and the page updates seen.  I tried expanding the ajax call below and the xhr gave a object but it seems like all defaults.  The desc and error were both error.  Why this behaviour, how do I fix the failure?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    success: function () {
        sxml00;
    },
    error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err + "\n");
    }
});
```

Comment: Is this form related and page reloads due to not preventing default submit process thereby aborting ajax? Sure sounds like it if alert slows it down

Comment: Thanks.  I do prevent default but return immediately.  Even when I comment out that section this fails exactly as stated.  It is very odd

Answer (score 0):

It was the browser.  FF 80.0.1 fails intermittently as described.  FF Developer 81.0b9 works everytime.  HTH.